# Mapbox Markers in Wrong Place

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I've made a simple mapbox map using the [mapbox.js API](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.0.1/l-mapbox-map/) and following [several examples they have on their site](https://www.mapbox.com/help/markers/). To display the marker location I'm calling a .geojson file, however the markers appear fairly off place even to the point that some load on top of the Ocean.

Someone said I'm calling the geojson file twice but I checked and it's being loaded once.

JS code is:

```js
// Mapbox
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'token_here';

var mapCol = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets').setView([5.5, -73.249], 6);
var filters = document.getElementById('filters');
var markers = L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL('regions.geojson');

markers.on('ready', function(e) {
    var typesObj = {},
        types = [];
    var features = e.target._geojson.features;
    for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
        typesObj[features[i].properties['description']] = true;
    }
    for (var key in typesObj) {
        if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(typesObj, key)) {
            types.push(key);
        }
    }
    var checkboxes = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
        var item = filters.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        var checkbox = item.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
        var label = item.appendChild(document.createElement('label'));
        checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
        checkbox.id = types[j];
        checkbox.checked = true;
        label.innerHTML = types[j];
        label.setAttribute('for', types[j]);
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', update);
        checkboxes.push(checkbox);
    }

    function update() {
        var enabled = {};
        for (var k = 0; k < checkboxes.length; k++) {
            if (checkboxes[k].checked) enabled[checkboxes[k].id] = true;
        }
        markers.setFilter(function(feature) {
            return feature.properties['description'] in enabled;
        });
    }
}).addTo(mapCol);

mapCol.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

This is the issue: markers are images, and this page has a broad rule about images, saying that they should have a bottom margin. This moves the markers north, into the sea.

The issue can be fixed by making the CSS rule more precise.

Comment: Thanks man you are very cool. Do you think adding a rule to Mapbox markers that overrides any CSS someone might have on their site/app is a good idea? Really had no idea my CSS could impact the map in any way.

Comment: .marker {margin: 0;} put it in the roughly right place regardless of zoom. It's still slightly to the left. But you can fix that with CSS